# Minimum element in next step in Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

This code finds the minimum of each row and scans the adjoining elements to find the next minimum. But I don't want it to return to the previous row. For example, for row 2, the min is 0.021. I want it to scan the elements 0.28 (row 2), 0.78 (row 3), 0.85 (row 3) and not 0.34 (row 1), 0.002 (row 1).

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#Pe = np.random.rand(3,3) 
Pe = np.array([[0.32, 0.34 , 0.002],
       [0.74, 0.28, 0.021],
       [0.69, 0.78, 0.85]])
b = np.zeros((Pe.shape[0], 2))

Pw=0.5

for row_n, row in enumerate(Pe):
    # Get row min
    b[row_n][0] = np.min(row)
   
    # Get surroundings min
    i = np.argmin(row)
    near = []
    if row_n > 0:
      near.append(Pe[row_n-1][i])
    if row_n+1 < b.shape[0]:
      near.append(Pe[row_n+1][i])
    if i > 0:
      near.append(Pe[row_n][i-1])
    if i+1 < b.shape[1]:
      near.append(Pe[row_n][i+1])
    b[row_n][1] = min(near)

print(b)
```

Current output:

```
[[0.002 0.021]
[0.021 0.002]
[0.69 0.74]]
```

Output I want:

```
[[0.002 0.021]
[0.021 0.28]
[0.69 0.78]]
```

Comment: I removed the tag seaborn as your question itself has nothing to do with seaborn or matplotlib. Please always remove irrelevant code details. Having said this, the use of [`pylab` is now discouraged by matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use numpy arrays, you should try to avoid explicit iterations using for loops. [scipy's ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#filter-functions) module can efficiently address tasks like that described in your question as it provides convenient sliding windows functions. Here, we use the [minimum filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import minimum_filter as mf

#Pe = np.random.rand(3,3) 
Pe = np.array([[0.32, 0.34 , 0.002],
       [0.74, 0.28, 0.021],
       [0.69, 0.78, 0.85]])
b = np.zeros((Pe.shape[0], 2))

#the footprint of the window, i.e., we do not consider the value itself 
#(the center of the footprint array) or any value in the row above
ft = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1]])
#applying scipy's minimum filter
#mode defines what should be considered as values at the edges
#setting the edges to INF
Pe_min = mf(Pe, footprint=ft, mode="constant", cval=np.inf)

#finding rowwise index of the minimum value using np.argmin()
idx = Pe.argmin(axis=1)

#retrieving minimum values and filtered values
b[:, 0] = np.take_along_axis(Pe, idx[None].T, 1).T[0]
b[:, 1] = np.take_along_axis(Pe_min, idx[None].T, 1).T[0]

print(b)
```

Sample output:

```
[[0.002 0.021]
 [0.021 0.28 ]
 [0.69  0.78 ]]
```

It should be noted that `np.argmin` returns the first minimum value per row if the same minimum occurs more than once. However, this situation was not considered in your question.

Comment: Can this be used for say, 5x5 matrix?

Comment: The footprint array is of size 3x3 as I understood that you want to consider only the neighbor cells of the minimum values. The input array `Pe` can be of whatever shape.

Comment: I was thinking of a modification. If I want the code to start with min value of the first row and then progress by scanning the nearby elements (the same and the succeeding row) without calculating the min value for each row.